# How do I test the values of a select statement in react testing library

Tags: reactjs, react-testing-library, react-typescript

I've got a component that grabs the primary names out of an array of names based on it's role, and then creates those as the options within the select statement. The field is required, and I want to test the values within the field.

I'm using react testing library to do this, but man am I new to this stuff. Checkout my code below, essentially I wanna know how to grab a value from a select statement to assert it. Bonus points for the man that teaches a man how to fish, how do you guys check the values that are currently within a test, do you have a way of console logging the elements you use the get commands on?

Here's my code for the test:
[image: test code]

And here's the code for the component:
[image: component code]

The options are just random values of names of people, there will be no default blank option once it's created that function, and it will auto select the first value

Comment: Please provide your code as a snippet rather than images, makes it easier for people to help you.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is a very specific case, that we cannot reproduce in a codesandbox as we don't have your components and logic.

However, there are some questions that come to mind and might help you.

I see that you're firing a change event in an input, then a blur and then a click. You can probably use the `user-event` library and use `userEvent.type` and `userEvent.click` to simulate a user behavior. This can help you get rid of that blur and your test would be more legible.

The `await getBy...` query does not make sense, as getBy is a synchronous query, and you only need to use the `await` with findBy queries.

I don't understand what the test is suppossed to test. Querying a text inside a innerHTML can be done differently, by doing `expect(x).toHaveTextContent('myText')` or if you want to query inside another element you can use `within`, to do something like: `within(getByLabelText('Main Contact')).getByText('hello')`.

This `within` function is really useful when testing values inside of a dropdown, so that you don't query the whole screen, and instead you query only the specific element.

Comment: I just want to grab the select values, tried a bunch of ways to extract the values, and this was where I stopped. I'm rather new and learned a bunch from you input, the findBy may be why it isn't grabbing the data, as well as the click event. If I do a click event on a dropdown, how would I go about selecting the options? say 'Pallavi Kiran' is one of the values, how do I simulate selecting that within the input?

Comment: How does a user select that input? With a click? If so, just find a selector for that option and click it. `userEvent.click(screen.getByText('myOption'))`